# err trying to extending user model in django restframework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I would like to extend Django's user model using a `OneToOneField` in my Django api project, but I'm getting a weird error. I'm hoping someone can help me out.  Below is my code and the error message.

**models.py:**

```
  class Profile(models.Model):
    yearOfExperience = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    profession = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    dp = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    qualification = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    phoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)


@receiver(post_save, sender=CustomUser)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.profile.save()
```

**serializer**:

```
  class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(source = 'pk', read_only = True)
    username = serializers.CharField(source = 'user.username', read_only = True)
    email = serializers.CharField(source = 'user.email', read_only=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'username', 'yearOfExperience',
            'qualification', 'profession', 'phoneNumber' 
        )

    def create(self, validated_data, instance=None):
        if 'user' in validated_data:
            user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        user = CustomUser.objects.create(**validated_data)
        profile = Profile.objects.update_or_create(user=user, **validated_data)
        return user
```

**apiView:**

```
class ProfileListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    queryset =  Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

**Error message:**

```
File "/home/olaneat/Desktop/filez/project/django/funzone/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 500, in __init__
    raise TypeError("%s() got an unexpected keyword argument '%s'" % (cls.__name__, kwarg))
TypeError: CustomUser() got an unexpected keyword argument 'yearOfExperience'
```

Comment: `yearOfExperience` is in `Profile` model, where is this `CustomUser` model ?

Comment: You can't just pass all the data for the profile creation to create a `CustomUser` as well because the fields surely wouldn't be the same? Also you're doing a check to see if `user` is in the data from the profile creation, so what exactly is that data?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're missing the user one to one field to your profile model so
add it there

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

Since you're using `post_save` for your profile, there's no need for the `.create` in your serializer. So something like this:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only = True)
    email = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'username', 'yearOfExperience',
            'qualification', 'profession', 'phoneNumber' 
        )

    def get_username(self, obj):
        return obj.user.username

    def get_email(self, obj):
        return obj.user.email
```

now just post from the API view and the profile will be created.

If however, you want to keep the `.create` for the option to add new users from the profile API then perhaps something like this:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only = True)
    email = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'username', 'yearOfExperience',
            'qualification', 'profession', 'phoneNumber' 
        )

    def create(self, validated_data, instance=None):
        if 'user' in validated_data:
            user = validated_data.pop('user')
        else:
            user = CustomUser.objects.create(**validated_data)
        profile, created_profile = Profile.objects.update_or_create(user=user, **validated_data)
        return profile

    def get_username(self, obj):
        return obj.user.username
    
    def get_email(self, obj):
        return obj.user.email
```

Comment: i've tried the api without the .create method & i'm getting this err django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: details_profile.user_id

Comment: that's because the user you are logged in with already has a profile. Go to /admin and delete the profile, then try again.

Comment: i've deleted my entire db and ran a fresh migration, but it still same tin, seem like am getting some other stuff wrong

Comment: that doesn't help because the new user you create will also have a new profile automatically created with post_save and you cant have 2 profiles for one user. To test profile creation just delete the profile from admin and create a new one from the API view.